# script works in one folder on all spreadsheets and fails in another folder with new spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that opens a spreadsheet in google sheets to it's last edited row, first column. It works on a number of spreadsheets in a particular folder. I've created a new group of spreadsheets in a different folder and installed the same script. None of the them work, opening they default to col A row1. I think the default for onOpen is col A row 1. Any help greatly appreciated

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.setActiveCell("A" + sheet.getLastRow());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This used to work in the old version of spreadsheets, it doesn't in the new version.

This change is intentional from google and is the subject of this issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3928&q=onOpen&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner

See also the release track mentioned in the issue.